# Create table with values from another table

Tags: mysql

I have a "users" table. DDL:

```
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
user_id INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
goal VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
age INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
gender VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
country VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
city VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
comment VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL)""")
```

I want to create "show_usesr" table, DDL:

```
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS shown_users(
id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
user_id INTEGER,
shown_id INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY (user_id, shown_id),
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE)""")
```

By default every user must be shown to itself, well for every `user_id` from `users` table must be a record in `shown_users` table `user_id - shown_id`

I found `AS` keyword, but what about `foreign key`?

Currently, my statement looks like this.

```
CREATE TABLE shown_users AS SELECT user_id FROM users FOREIGN KEY (user_id, show_id) REFERENCES users (user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE; -- Wrong
```

How I must improve it?

P.s. I'm a novice in SQL, so if you have any remarks please tell me about them.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking for but I do know that an FK has to reference the same number (and type etc) of every column specified - you have 2-1 . And if 'every user_id from users table must be a record in shown_users table' is the case then the FK should be in users,

Comment: You right, just wrong copy :)